# Pycharm not detecting errors

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've encountered with an strange issue. I'm currently running Pycharm 5 for development of a Django project. There exists a specific file that Pycharm does not catch errors of it. For instance, if I read a variable that does not exist, Pycharm does not detect it. If I call an unresolved reference, Pycharm does not  detect it. It does not detect anything. But things get stranger when I want to edit another file that is inside the directory where the previous file exists. But in this case, Everthing is OK.

I tried both removing .idea folder and also invalidating cache and restarting Pycharm but non of them worked!

Any idea how to fix this weird issue?

**Update 1:**

For instance, Pycharm does not detect that the variable used in `if` statement is not previously defind:

```
if dfsdffsdfdsf:
   a = 2
```

Comment: Without specifics its hard to say, does the calls to that class have a try/except wrapped around it?

Comment: I've seen this issue occur personally when I open a non-project file.